# How to choose one right data type from several detected

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on one problem. I have a `list<string>` of detected data types ("int", "double", "string", "bool", "datetime", "timespan", "datetimeoffset").

Now I need to choose something like "default" one data type that will be used for all values in array. How to create (theoretically) the logic to setting the appropriate data type?

For example if was detected at least one string, default data type will be defined as string, because this type can "store" also other data types, such as bool or date.

Name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear to me whether you're asking for help in working out the right rules to apply, or *implementing* those rules. Either way, we'll need more information... what's to stop you *always* using strings, for example? What criteria do you have?

Comment: Use List<object>.

Comment: There is no singular correct answer to this, because it depends entirely on what you're actually trying to achieve. In general, guessing data types, or trying to go for the "most general type, but not too general" inevitably leads to mistakes, somewhere, somehow. What's your strategy for handling those mistakes, and why wouldn't you always apply it instead of guessing in the first place? Who or what is using the array, and what do *they* need?

Comment: I try to find a way to detect the most likely data type. Something like in Excel when you insert a value program decides whether it is a string, a numerical value, or a date...

Comment: Did you try List<dynamic>

Comment: Excel actually kinda sucks at that (though that's not it's fault). I'm continuously annoyed when it fails to see "2018-01-01" as a date because the system is using a different locale, for example. Or when it has to guess whether "01-02-2018" is January or February, and guesses wrong. And don't get me started on the decimal separator -- no, "12,34" isn't "12,340". And is `0, 1, 0, 0, 0` a list of `bool` or a list of `int`? Did you want me to write `false, true, false, false, false` instead? Fortunately Excel allows me to override the format...

Comment: With all that said -- assuming you have some sort of type-by-string-representation detection going, and you detect *multiple* types, then the best you can do is give up and defer to `string` as the only thing that can truly represent everything. The alternative is to use conversions that are either unintuitive or plain wrong -- even `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset` is suspect (what time zone should we add -- the local one or UTC?), and there's really no common ground to be found in the other types.

Comment: I now, it is not a simple question. For better understanding, I provide an example. Imagine that program detects - string & bool. Then selects the string as default data type. If will be detected boolean, int and double, program selects double. Later, user can manually change (in GUI) default detected type, but I need to choose somehow something as "default".

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you want correctly, you can make a method like this :

```
public static List<object> GetMostLikelyType(List<string> inputs)
{
    List<object> result = new List<object>() ;
    int num;
    double d;
    DateTime dt;
    bool b;
    TimeSpan ts;
    DateTimeOffset dto;
    if (inputs.All(i => int.TryParse(i, out num)))
        result = inputs.Select(x => (object)int.Parse(x)).ToList();
    else if (inputs.All(i => double.TryParse(i, out d)))
        result = inputs.Select(x => (object)double.Parse(x)).ToList();
    else if (inputs.All(i => DateTime.TryParse(i, out dt)))
        result = inputs.Select(x => (object)DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();
    else if (inputs.All(i => bool.TryParse(i, out b)))
        result = inputs.Select(x => (object)bool.Parse(x)).ToList();
    else if (inputs.All(i => TimeSpan.TryParse(i, out ts)))
        result = inputs.Select(x => (object)TimeSpan.Parse(x)).ToList();
    else if (inputs.All(i => DateTimeOffset.TryParse(i, out dto)))
        result = inputs.Select(x => (object)DateTimeOffset.Parse(x)).ToList();
    else
        result = inputs.Select(x => (object)x.ToString()).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

And then use it for your *List* (respective outputs is commented) :

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() {"2016/7/3","2025/12/01" };
//List of DateTime objects
List<string> strings2 = new List<string>() { "25", "21.12" };
//List of Double objects
List<string> strings3 = new List<string>() { "true", "false" };
//List of bool objects
List<string> strings4 = new List<string>() { "12", "0" };
//List of int objects
List<string> strings5 = new List<string>() { (new TimeSpan(2,3,3)).ToString(), "0" };
//List of TimeSpan objects
List<string> strings6 = new List<string>() { "2016/7/3" , "3"};
//string

var result = GetMostLikelyType(strings);
var result2 = GetMostLikelyType(strings2);
var result3 = GetMostLikelyType(strings3);
var result4 = GetMostLikelyType(strings4);
var result5 = GetMostLikelyType(strings5);
var result6 = GetMostLikelyType(strings6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare everything as an object since object is the base type for everything.

then you iterate through the list and test with typeof.

```
list<object> tt
```

in your loop use :

```
 if (tt[I].GetType() == typeof(Integer))
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use a list of Object or list of dynamic:

```
List<object> stuff = new List<object>();

stuff.add("test");
stuff.add(35);

Console.WriteLine((string)stuff[0]);
Console.WriteLine((int)stuff[1]);
```

and here is dynamic example:

```
var list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(123);
list.Add(new
{
Name = "Lorem Ipsum"
});
```